# Delete Rows with respect to cell value= None

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsx

[Original Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d7v2.png)
[After deleting Empty cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzcfe.png)
I'm new to python... I have a code it delete rows if cell value is `None(row=1 to lstrw, col=3)` but it doesn't delete some of the rows containing none value in respective cell. Pictures are attached for reference.

```py
wb = load_workbook(r"C:\Users\hassan.a\Desktop\Monthly report\ws\Data.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
endrow = ws.max_row
for x in range(1, endrow):
    if ws.cell(row=x, column=3).value == None:
        ws.delete_rows(x)
    else:
        continue
print (ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value)
wb.save(r"C:\Users\hassan.a\Desktop\Monthly report\ws\Va.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ws.cell(row=x, column=3).value == None:
            ws.delete_rows(x)
```

this part you put '=' like '=='
try to change that and see if its work

Answer (score 0):

> it gives error.

if ws.cell(row=x, column=3).value = None:
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax